# time difference of rm single tar file between large and small size

Tags: rhel, tar, performance, rm, io

If I have a file `data.tar` and one is **1 MB** in size versus one that is **10 GB** in size versus one that is **10.0 TB** in size (yes 10 terabytes is correct) why is there a time difference in doing a `rm` on either of them?  What is the cause of the time difference?  What amount of time should be reasonable to expect for the `rm` command to complete on a 10tb file?  Should there be a [noticeable] time difference?

*this was from a test run of how I am going to migrate some data, and I did a `tar -cf data.tar /data/*` to create it.  When removing it, it took about 20-30 seconds.*

This is currently on RHEL 7.9, where the file system is XFS 4.5.  Also interested in this regarding RHEL 8.8 having XFS 5.0.  And this is on a server (dell r740) having 768 GB of RAM using enterprise class SAS SSD's and a PERC H740P, so I'm expecting this time difference reason to be solely within Linux and having nothing to do with hardware shortcomings.

Comment: Have you think about the time to mark all blocks/extends (of deleted file) as free?

Comment: This is most probably caused by write barriers on XFS. http://www.ep.ph.bham.ac.uk/general/support/raid/raidperf11.html has some benchmarks on deletion. Although rather old (Fedora 10), but you can see the difference on the barrier-setting.

Comment: by the way, the unit for byte is capital "B", not small "b" (which is a bit, which is 1/8 of a byte, at least on any machine we care to talk about). Mega- is capital "M" (not "m", which is milli-, which is one billionth of mega), and giga- and tera- are also capital "G" and "T", respectively (there's at least no potential for prefix confusion there).

Answer (score 2):

> XFS

> Should there be a [noticeable] time difference?

That depends on the extent allocation; theoretically, both might just be one large contiguous range of blocks, and deleting that would take the same amount of time. Removal of one filesystem entry, freeing of the extent, freeing of the metadata block, updating of the free space table.

In expectation, though, the allocation will not have happened at once, and the extent list / Btree for the larger file will be more complex, necessitating a traversal of a potentially deep tree. 20 s still seems excessive for that alone.

@stoney [brought up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/239465/stoney) brought up write barriers, and that sounds plausible enough, but I still have doubts it'll take 20s.

I'm running a short pseudo-benchmark…